# Identify the cause of the slowness of a Java EE web application

Tags: java, performance, profiling

Good morning,
*I admit to being quite new in the world of programming, but I can not find the solution to this problem I found the front and no one can help me, so I tried to ask here.*

I have a batch of data loading, developed with hibernate and native queries with a sqlserver database.
On the production machine is very slow but the machine is much more powerful than the one that I use as a local laboratory.

The dabatase has already indexes, many queries are native for speeding reason, the amount of RAM is huge, so I can not isolate the cause of the problem, or rather I do not know how to "analyze" a java application running for figure out where the problem might be.

If you have 10 minutes to spare, you can help me find a way/explain how to analyze the critical points of a java application?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is way too broad. There are many potential explanations; and  that simply doesn't fit into a single, reasonable answer. Seriously: you being a "newbie" ... I doubt that this can be done remotely. Aren't there folks in your team that you can directly talk to? For sure a Java EE application didn't came into existence over night; so there must be people that have been working with it for a while ... if at all ... you could ask at quora.com - probably better chances to get a "discussion" going there.

Comment: Check Fetch types (https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/) and modes (http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/). It may be that your queries are not optimised so they work in local environment quite well with not so much data but stuck in live.

Comment: Ok @GhostCat, I try to add some details

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using batch querying then may be the batch size is somehow big, keep reducing the amount and running until you get an admissible performance. 
I once had such issue because I didn't used batch querying, but after I started using batch querying everything worked well.

Answer (score -1):

There may be a lot of reasons. Give us some more data about you app. The structure of entities, queries, something more precise.

Comment: Yes, you don't have enough reputation yet to comment. But no, writing up answers to cover up for that is not a good idea. Because answers are answers. Not comments.